# how to Install OpenCv on my home directory in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile and install OpenCV on my home directory (so I can have several versions installed)

I have this option when I am calling cmak:

```
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/mans/local/opencv -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  -D WITH_INF_ENGINE=ON -D ENABLE_CXX11=ON
```

but when I build the code and try to install it, I am getting this error:

```
-- Install configuration: "Release"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/share/licenses/opencv4.  Maybe
  need administrative privileges.


Makefile:61: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

As I want to install on my home directory, I can not use

```
sudo make install
```

as it will install openCV on root and I don't want to do this.

## Edit

I am using this bash script to build and install OpenCV from git repository.

```
WITH_INF_ENGINE=true # should be buildwith Intel Inference Engineen


workingDir="$HOME/local"

downloadDir="$workingDir/downloadedFiles"


if [ ! -d "$workingDir" ]; then
    mkdir "$workingDir"
fi

cd $workingDir
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv $downloadDir/opencv
cd $downloadDir/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmakeParameters="-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$workingDir/opencv -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON "
if $WITH_INF_ENGINE; then
     source /opt/intel/computer_vision_sdk/bin/setupvars.sh
     cmakeParameters="$cmakeParameters -D WITH_INF_ENGINE=ON -D ENABLE_CXX11=ON"
fi
echo "$cmakeParameters"
cmake "$cmakeParameters" ..
make -j $(nproc)
make install
```

Comment: Have you tried **clean** reconfiguration with given CMake options? By "clean" I mean with `CMakeCache.txt` file removed from the build directory (or with all files removed from the build directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you mean to clear cash after I called cmake or before? I download OpenCV from git (using clone command) and then run cmake with the above configuration, then make and make install. I am going to delete everything and do it again.

Comment: "I am going to delete everything and do it again." - This would be the best. It is for the case, if you (suddenly) have called `cmake` without setting of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` before your final attempt. While this variable is definitely updated after you call `cmake` with it, some other variable(s) could be not updated. Among these variables it could be install path for the license files. (As a general rule: **usually** changing `cmake` settings after the first call **works**, but there are also subtle cases when it doesn't work.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev After rebuilding and trying to reinstall, I am getting the same error. I deleted all files related to the OpenCV and still getting this error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added the script that I am using to build OpenCV as it could be helpful to find the problem.

Comment: Hmm, this looks really strange. As base directory for install license files opencv uses `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR` variable, which is set by `GNUInstallDirs` module. Can you check the value of this variable (grep `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory)?